# How to handle hierarchical modules in Sitefinity with Babaganoush?

Tags: c#, sitefinity, babaganoush-sitefinity

How do you handle hierarchical modules when creating the model for your projects Dynamic module?

Say we have a module called Careers with a parent ContentType of "Jobs" and a child of "Applications".

Comment: To answer my own question, yes it does:

Say we have a Module "Jobs" with a ContentType of Position and a child of Applications

Add a property to your application model like so:

    public PositionModel Position { get; set; }

In the ApplicationModel constructor add this:

    if (sfContent.SystemParentId != Guid.Empty)
    {
       this.Position = sfContent.SystemParentItem as PositionModel;
    }

Easy!

Comment: To answer your own question, create an answer (not a comment).

Comment: @Eric Finn, stakoverflow would not let me create an answer and told me to leave a comment :)

Answer (score 3):

To set up a hierarchy of models, you will need to implement the `IHierarchy` interface on your dynamic model you've created. This means you will have a `Parent` property of type `DynamicModel`.

In your constructor, assign the `SystemParentItem` to the parent by passing it into the constructor of the parent model you've created elsewhere (to map the property values).

Here's an example of how the `JobModel` would look like:

```
public class JobModel : DynamicModel, IHierarchy
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DynamicModel Parent { get; set; }

    public override string MappedType 
    {
        get
        {
            return "Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Applications.Job";
        }
    }

    public JobModel()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public JobModel(DynamicContent sfContent)
        : base(sfContent)
    {
        if (sfContent != null)
        {
            Description = sfContent.GetStringSafe("Description");
            Parent = new CareerModel(sfContent.SystemParentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me add to this by saying that your CareerModel (parent content type) needs to implement the interface of IDynamic too in order for this to worki.

Comment: Hi Basem, I am getting errors, apparently the sfContent.SystemParentItem is having difficulty: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Also in the web api the parent data comes out like so: <Parent i:nil="true"/>

Comment: Seems like Sitefinity broke the SystemParentItem property. Use the extension sfContent.GetParent() coming from Babaganoush.Sitefinity.Extensions instead.